# Is there a way to select multiple values in a case when in sql server

Tags: sql-server, case

I have the following query

```
    SELECT
        ip.ITEMID AS ItemID,
        ip.CoUkScreenName AS Name,
        CASE 
            WHEN
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                    (SELECT c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS c
                        WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID
                        GROUP BY c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology
                    ) AS CountResult
                ) = 1
            THEN 
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.CarbonFP FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS c WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID)
            ELSE
                NULL
        END AS CarbonFP,
        CASE 
            WHEN
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                    (SELECT c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS c
                        WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID
                        GROUP BY c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology
                    ) AS CountResult
                ) = 1
            THEN 
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.Unit FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS c WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID)
            ELSE
                NULL
        END AS Unit,
        CASE 
            WHEN
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                    (SELECT c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS c
                        WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID
                        GROUP BY c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology
                    ) AS CountResult
                ) = 1
            THEN 
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.Methodology FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS c WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID)
            ELSE
                NULL
        END AS Methodology
    FROM
        MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION ip
        INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT (cp.ParentItemID) FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS cp) AS p ON p.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID
```

This works just fine but I was wondering if it was possible to select all 3 values in the same case rather than having to do it one at a time, or if there is a better way to structure this query, as it looks to be inefficient (I have no current issues with the query - just thinking about scalability) having to do the same query three times just to get those three values

Comment: Maybe check out CROSS APPLY? You should compare actual execution plans and I think there are performance gains, but if nothing you'd have cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks @MK_ I'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT . . .,
       c.*
FROM MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION ip INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT cp.ParentItemID
      FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS cp
     ) p
     ON p.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT c.*
      FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] c
      WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID
     ) c
```

In general, you should not be using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`.  In your original version, the three columns could be coming from different rows.  In this version, all three columns come from the same row, but which row is indeterminate.

EDIT:

To only match when the count is 1:

```
SELECT . . .,
       c.*
FROM MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION ip INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT cp.ParentItemID
      FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS cp
     ) p
     ON p.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology
      FROM [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] c
      WHERE c.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID 
      GROUP BY c.CarbonFP, c.Unit, c.Methodology
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) c
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, using this query I now get duplicates and don't get the products where we have null values for the three case statements

Comment: I believe that OP wants the TOP 1 result only if the COUNT (after doing GROUP BY) returns exactly the value 1. That explains why this query gives duplicates, because the check for Count = 1 has gone missing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the edit, it now returns all the results with nulls but it now only has the values for when the original count is 1 rather than when the result of the group by is 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon for pointing me in the right direction.  I have managed to get the same result set using the following query (not sure if it is any more efficient but it looks better as it doesn't have repeated queries):

```sql
SELECT 
    ip.ITEMID,
    ip.CoUkScreenName AS Name,
    u.CarbonFP, 
    u.Unit, 
    u.Methodology
FROM MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION ip 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        DISTINCT cp.ParentItemID
    FROM 
        [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS cp
    ) AS p ON p.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        c.ParentItemID, 
        c.CarbonFP, 
        c.Unit, 
        c.Methodology
    FROM 
        [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts] AS c
    INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                p.ParentItemID 
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                    ParentItemID, 
                    CarbonFP, 
                    Unit, 
                    Methodology
                FROM 
                    [dbo].[vw_carbon_ChildProducts]
                GROUP BY 
                    ParentItemID, 
                    CarbonFP, 
                    Unit, 
                    Methodology) AS p
            GROUP BY 
                p.ParentItemID
            HAVING COUNT(p.ParentItemID) = 1
        )  AS f ON f.ParentItemID = c.ParentItemID
    GROUP BY 
        c.ParentItemID, 
        c.CarbonFP, 
        c.Unit, 
        c.Methodology
     ) AS u ON u.ParentItemID = ip.ITEMID
```